# Setting a variable based on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails 3 and I would like to set the storage variable  based on the current environment, like below:

```
 #if enviroment = development or test 
    :storage => :filesystem,
    #else
    :storage => :s3,
    #end
```

What would your approach be? I've thought about setting an environment variable, but I think that there must be a better way.

Thanks for your time
Simone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is use the built-in environment setup in rails. The variables set in the environments directory will override the config/environment

**config/environment.rb**

```
ATTACHMENT_OPTIONS = {:storage => :filesystem}
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
ATTACHMENT_OPTIONS = {:storage => :s3}
```

Then later in your app, just ask ATTACHMENT_OPTIONS[:storage] -- no if/else throughout your app.

Answer (score 8):

`Rails.env` will give you what you're looking for.

You can also use

```
Rails.env.development?
Rails.env.test?
Rails.env.production?
Rails.env.your_custom_environment?
```

To test for those specific environments.

Comment: Thank you! I have to put the test inside a model, and with Netbeans I always got an error. Here the code:
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
    :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
    :default_url => '/:attachment/missing_:style.jpg',
    :styles => { :small => "80x80>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
    if (Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?)  
      :storage => :filesystem
    else
     :storage => :s3
    end
    :default_style => :thumb,
    :bucket => 'josha_pictures',
    :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :

Comment: What's the error? and would you mind editing your question and putting the code there?

Comment: why not use ternary operator instead of if/else?

:storage => (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) ? :filesystem : :s3